# How can I restart DAI with current character?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Does anybody know how to restart "Dragon Age: Inquisition" with my current character?

I deleted my starting saves, but now I want to go through the game again with my old settings and appearance. I don't know what exactly I need to change in the save files.

Comment: Did you create your character in the keep online?

Answer (score 1):

If you have deleted all your saved games, including temporary and auto save, then it may be required to recreate a new world state in the Keep and sync again with DA:I.